# Creating range from normal collection index and reversed collection index

Tags: swift, generics, collections, reverse

*(Simplified example of a bigger problem. Yes, I know that this specific dumbed down example can be solved in much easier ways.)*

I have a collection containing some ASCII code points of which I'd like to remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
func foo<T: BidirectionalCollection>(_ buffer: T) -> String
    where T.Iterator.Element == UInt8,
          T.SubSequence.Iterator.Element == T.Iterator.Element
{
    if let valueStart = buffer.index(where: { $0 != 0x20 /* SP */ }),
       let valueEnd = buffer.reversed().index(where: { $0 != 0x20 /* SP */ })
    {
        return String(bytes: buffer[valueStart ... valueEnd], encoding: .utf8)!
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

However, I get this error:

> error: binary operator '...' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T.Index' and 'ReversedIndex'

The documentation of [`BidirectionalCollection`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/protocol/BidirectionalCollection/#func--reversed) states:

> If you need a reversed collection of the same type, you may be able to use the collection's sequence-based or collection-based initializer.

However, when I try embedding `buffer.reversed()` in a `T()`, I get this error:

> error: 'T' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

Because, apparently, the initializers are defined somewhere else.

In the end, I don't need the whole reversed collection to be of a certain type. I just want to be able to build ranges from the original collection's indices and the corresponding reversed collection's indices.

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the index for the underlying collection from a `ReversedIndex`, you can simply use its [`base`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/reversedindex/1784731-base) property.

Although note that because of the way `ReversedCollection` [is implemented](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Reverse.swift#L87), this will actually return the index *above* the given index in the base collection (as `startIndex` is mapped to `endIndex` – which is a 'past the end' index).

Therefore you can simply use a half-open range operator `..<` in order to make this index the non-inclusive upper bound:

```
func foo<T: BidirectionalCollection>(_ buffer: T) -> String
    where T.Iterator.Element == UInt8,
    T.SubSequence.Iterator.Element == T.Iterator.Element
{
    if let valueStart = buffer.index(where: {$0 != 0x20}),
        let valueEnd = buffer.reversed().index(where: {$0 != 0x20})?.base
    {
        // goes without saying that this will crash if String(bytes:encoding:) returns nil.
        return String(bytes: buffer[valueStart ..< valueEnd], encoding: .utf8)!
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Or, in cases where you need to work with the index itself, you could use `Optional`'s [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional/1539476-map) method in conjunction with the collection's `index(before:)` method to get the index before:

```
let index = (buffer.reversed().index{ $0 != 0x20 }?.base).map{ buffer.index(before: $0) }
```